# Raising an Exception within a Class Method

Tags: python, class, exception

I have a class that checks if a file exists or not and creates a file object if the file exists
else catches an exception if the file does not exist or there are permissions issue.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import pandas
    import yaml

    class FileChange():

         def __init__(self, file_name='manifile.yml'):
            ''' to create a factfile object '''
            self.file_name = file_name
            self.checkfile()


        def checkfile(self):
            '''to check if the factfile exists or not '''
            try:
                with open(self.file_name, 'r') as yml_file:
                        self.yml_dict = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)
            except (IOError,FileNotFoundError):
                print('Unable to open file or File does not exist')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Run the script with the YML fact file name you would like to edit")
    elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
        FILE_NAME = sys.argv[1]
        print(FILE_NAME)
        F = FileChange(FILE_NAME)
```

I would like to create a class object using this class and catch/handle the exception thrown in the object if the file does not exists.

I am using this in 2 ways.
1. By creating an object 
from filechange import *
F=FileChange('dummyfile.yml')  where dummyfile does not exist and hence it should show me the message and exit.

2. I am also running this as a py script utility (cmd>filechange.py dummyfile.yml) and passing the filename as parameter.  Even then the filename, I give is wrong. It should give me an exception and exit. The main code for this file is added

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to tell what you mean by "I would like to create a class object using this class and catch/handle the exception thrown in the object if the file does not exists.". What doesn't work with your current code that you want to correct? What is your end goal?

Comment: I have just updated the code and the usage scenarios. Let me learn from you and become a better programmer. Your inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to add in a controlled custom exception.
If that is correct, then this code will work for you

Code:

```
class IncorrectFile(Exception):
    pass
```

Then just call it up by do raise IncorrectFile.

If it is not a custom made one, then just raise (Choose a error)